# Can coding DNA be used for DNA fingerprinting?

Tags: genetics, molecular-biology, dna, molecular-genetics

I am confused if coding DNA can be used for DNA fingerprinting because I have read that non-coding segments of DNA are used to identify and analyze DNA. I want to know if coding DNA segments are of equal length in all individuals?

Comment: It's not non-coding regions in general, it's specific repeat sequences - microsatellites - that are highly variable. In principle you could use a full genome sequence to identify individuals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When selecting sequences to use for DNA fingerprinting, you have to use sequences that are highly variable within the population.  Coding sequences mostly aren't, and they aren't going to vary much in size, the way tandem repeat sections do.

Comment: You are correct, but even so you need to provide a reference to document your answer and to allow the reader to find out more details.